# How to edit hue saturation and luminance by using GPUImageFilters in android Java?

Tags: java, android, image-processing, opengl-es, gpuimage

I want to ajust the `hue, saturation and luminace` of an image for `specific color shades` using OpenGLES or GPUImageFilter.

It should basically like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there's no built-in functionality for it in this library. So, you can implement it yourself by extending `GPUImageFilter` and writing a corresponding shader.

You can reuse existing Hue, Saturation, and Luminance filters.
The idea is simple - you're passing an additional parameter (color) to the shader. Based on this color and the color of the current pixel, you can choose if the current pixel should be affected by the shader or not.

Comment: How do I add the filters from shader to the GPUImageView?